# Accuracy of threshold images

Tags: normalized-difference-water-index, confusion-matrix, otsu

I am studying on identifying flood zones using Google Earth Engine.
I calculated the NDWI index for the Sentinel 2 image. Then I set a threshold according to the OTSU thresholding method.
I classified the resulting image as water and non-water according to the threshold value. I want to create confusion matrix using Google Earth images as reference image. Anyone have any ideas for this?  How can I calculate the accuracy of threshold images?

Comment: This question, including the lack of proper case in the title, is familiar. Did you delete a recent previous post?

Comment: Yes. I edited and asked again.

Comment: If you delete and repost, you destroy the comment trail and edit history. It also may cause the SE anti-spam defenses to ban your account. Editing automatically starts a review process to re-open closed Questions. If you try to subvert that process, you're *less* likely to get an answer.